# How can I send a visual selection to another file, at a line with a certain pattern?

Tags: vimscript

I'd like to be able to yank a visual selection and then append it to another file at a certain line (according to a pattern).

In particular (as shown in the attached screenshot), as an example i'd like to copy text from test.txt into a register perhaps create a visual selection and then, use the the w: command to send that to test2.txt (shown).
In the screenshot, I tried:
1. Get visual selection ;
2. Hit : followed by w +/John test2.txt

It says that it can't open test2.txt[image]

Comment: You want to append to the other file at a specified line? Because plain append would be `:w >>file`

Comment: Yes, i'm hoping that I can add it at a line with a pattern line "Exercises". That way when I look at that file later on, the text is where I want.

Comment: That might require opening the file properly

Comment: @aladdinoscopy Please edit your question and add more details. If possible, add an example of what you're trying to accomplish. Or describe how you're doing that right now. As it stands, it's very vague to elicit a good quality answer...

Comment: I think the `:w +/<search> <filename>` is not valid syntax. You probably can script something, if both files are open within vim using `search(), getline() and setbufline()`. I don't think there exists a ready available solution

Comment: thanks, okay. I'll look into that.